# Java: GC tuning in master for master-slaves set up?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How should I tune GC (e.g. the type of collector, min/max size of heap, size of new/old gen, ratio of Eden to survivor etc.) for the following scenario? (I'm using Sun JDK 6, and available memory is 1GB).

1) a master machine running tomcat which in turn runs a web app to show status of various node machines under the master

2) a node status message includes things like its CPU, memory, IO usage; typical message size is 1KB

3) a node sends 3 such messages per second to the master, and a master has 10 nodes under it

4) the master has to keep status data for the last one hour into its memory, so total status data that the master has to keep in memory is: 3kb * 3600 * 10 = 108MB

5) the master will of course need memory for its other tasks, so the JVM can get upto half GB but not more.

My specific question is, if I keep a bigger new gen, a lot of copying would occur because these objects would live at least for an hour; and if I keep old gen bigger, then a lot of minor collections will happen, so how do I go about this?

Comment: On 2), message size might be 1k but that doesn't mean you need 1k of memory to store the data. E.g. serialised forms are often much larger than well-packed in-memory representations. You might want to check this assumption!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Measure yourself!

Attach JVisualVM to the Tomcat process and *see* how it behaves under various loads.  You will most likely find the Visual GC plugin very useful.

See http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/monitoring-of-tomcat-with-visualvm-and-visualgc/ for inspiration.

Comment: but can you suggest some initial parameters based on this info?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even bother thinking about GC tuning until you have identified a real performance issue. The defaults will probably work fine.

Basically this is a fairly GC-light application. You're talking only 100k per second or so of memory allocations, and a working set around 100mb. That's pretty trivial for a modern server to handle.